# When i try to do require from folder i get Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

when I do require in one folder everything is fine, but when I create a folder and try to make require, an error occurs (require Error: Unknown module). What i do wrong ?

[image]
[image]

main.js

```
const tt = require('./roles/tata.js');
console.log(tt)
```

tata.js

```
module.exports = {
 asd: 'asd'
}
```

Comment: check your configurations, maybe its only set to import inside a folder.

Comment: i don't have any configuration

Comment: Please share package.json

Comment: i don' have packege.json, you can see all files on screenshot